# pouchDB to iriscouch syncing issue with remove

Tags: pouchdb, replicate, iriscouch

I have followed the tutorial http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html to the letter and the addition of new todos works great, so does the editing of todos but the deleting (remove) doesn't work.

i.e. In browser1 I add a todo and in browser2 it is displayed. Then in browser1 I delete the todo and it disappears but only in browser1, in browser2 it remains and if I log into my iriscouch it also still remains.

Anyone had the same issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of PouchDB are you using? 3.0.2 solves some issues with replication of deleted docs: http://pouchdb.com/2014/08/20/pouchdb-3.0.2.html.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.1 - i'll try 3.0.2